# google map crashes after resizing browser

Tags: google-maps, jquery-mobile

actually im trying to make a webapp with jquery-mobile and google maps v3.
i have a google map at the main page. On resizing with this page active everything works.
but on resizing in a subview called from the main page and then going back to the main page, there is just a little piece of gmap in the upper left corner.
Then on resizing the main page again the map is fine.

i tried to trigger the map on 'pagebeforeshow'- and 'pageshow'-events with 
`google.maps.event.trigger($("#map_canvas"), 'resize')`

but it doesn't solve my problem. the div for the map has the right size.

has anybody made the same experiences and has a solution?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

damn, that's dumb.

instead of

`google.maps.event.trigger($("#map_canvas"), 'resize')`

it should be something like this

```
 var map =  new google.maps.Map(.........);
 google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

works fine